# Update variable when checking checkbox

Tags: jquery, variables, object

I have a script with some variables, and I would like to update one of these variables depending on the checkbox being checked or not. The checkbox is unselected by default. What I have now is this:

```
var checked = $('#accept').attr('checked');
if (checked) {
    permission = "Y";
} else {
    permission = "N";
};
var track = {
    version: 123,
    id: 123456789,
    order: {
        sv1: 'Y',
        sv2: 'N',
        sv3: 'Name',
        sv4: permission,
        orderid: '123xyz'
    }
};
console.log(track);
```

I would like to update the content of the variable "permission" based on a click event of a checkbox:

```
$('#accept').click(function () {
      if (checked) {
      permission = "Y";
      } else {
      permission = "N";
      };
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/k6S3m/).

But how is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In order to update your object key (sv4) value:

http://jsfiddle.net/k6S3m/6/

If you already store the `permission` into your Object `track`, well, than don't hesitate to use your object and directly manipulate it and setting a new value to it's key using `=`.

```
var permission = $('#accept').is(':checked') ? "Y" : "N";

var track = {
    version: 123,
    id: 123456789,
    order: {
        sv1: 'Y',
        sv2: 'N',
        sv3: 'Name',
        sv4: permission,
        orderid: '123xyz'
    }
};
console.log( track.order.sv4 );                       // returns: N

$('#accept').change(function () {
    track.order.sv4 = this.checked ? "Y" : "N";
    console.log( track.order.sv4 );                   // returns: Y
});
```

<sup>Never forget to define internally your variables by setting `var`.</sup>

The `$('#accept').is(':checked')` uses the jQuery `.is()` method that returns a boolean (true/false) which than we set using `Ternary Operator ( ? : )` to `"Y"` / `"N"`

Comment: This solution is what I have been looking for. Thanks a lot, Roko.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this on click:

```
$('#accept').click(function () {
    var permission = this.checked ? "Y" : "N";
    console.log(permission);
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nguMT/)

Comment: i'd use onchange event instead

Comment: It works in the console.log, but it doesn't seem to update the 'permission' value inside the track object.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do:

```
$('#accept').click(function () {
      if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
          permission = "Y";
      } else {
          permission = "N";
      };
});
```

This way you'll change the variable if checkbox is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is you initialized `checked` properly, but obviously it won't get updated on clicking of checkbox. You will have to check that again. So try:

```
 $('#accept').click(function () {
     if ($('#accept').attr('checked')) {
        permission = "Y";
      } else {
         permission = "N";
      };
  alert(permission);
 });
```

Comment: Read on this page (comments sections) some more things

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this :
should be $('#accept').is(':checked') NOT if(checked)

[Fiddle][1]

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/k6S3m/4/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$('#accept').on('change', function () { track.order.s4 = this.checked ? 'Y' : 'N'; });
```